# How to work include zxing android project to other android project through "Is Library" option?

Tags: android, eclipse, zxing, android-library

I have customized the ZXing 1.7 library for my barcode scanning application and marked it as "Is Library" through Project Options in the Project menu of Eclipse.But when i try to add ZXing library to other android project through Project Options in the Project menu it generates some error.I have attached the screenshot of the error [Please refer the link ].How to solve this problem.I am using eclipse helios and android 2.1 Google API's

Answer (score 1):

close and re-open the project again, and try to tick the "Is Library option again" and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Eclipse cant find the path to the library project on your D drive.  I would delete it from your workspace and then re-import it with Copy Projects into Workspace checked.